# How to get <arrow key down> to focus on first google hit?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, google-search

At my school on a linux (Ubuntu) machine, if I google something and then press arrow key down, a cursor will show next to the first hit. I can then navigate down or up to select the link I want and press enter to go to the link.

Is this something built into Ubuntu? Can I get this functionality on my Windows 8 laptop?